# How to mount a logical volume?

Tags: linux, mount, lvm

I would like to mount /dev/sda2. How am I supposed to do that?

I have tried this, I'm not sure about the result, `df` still does not show the free space.

```
mount -v -o ro /dev/sda2 /data
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

Bellow is the output of `fdisk`, `df`, `lvmdiskscan`, `lvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`, `lvscan`, `pvdisplay`.

```
[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1030.8 GB, 1030792151040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 125320 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00034e05

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        1306     9972736   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_centos6264bit-lv_root: 8095 MB, 8095006720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 984 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_centos6264bit-lv_swap: 2113 MB, 2113929216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 257 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_centos6264bit-lv_root
                      7.3G  988M  6.0G  14% /
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   64M  389M  15% /boot



[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# lvmdiskscan
  /dev/ram0                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/root                     [       7.54 GiB]
  /dev/ram1                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/sda1                     [     500.00 MiB]
  /dev/vg_centos6264bit/lv_swap [       1.97 GiB]
  /dev/ram2                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/sda2                     [       9.51 GiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/ram3                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram4                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram5                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram6                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram7                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram8                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram9                     [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram10                    [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram11                    [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram12                    [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram13                    [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram14                    [      16.00 MiB]
  /dev/ram15                    [      16.00 MiB]
  2 disks
  17 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  1 LVM physical volume


[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_centos6264bit/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                vg_centos6264bit
  LV UUID                GuVsuq-Q0II-gcjX-6Pdp-7azY-FPub-25YWYR
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ,
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                7.54 GiB
  Current LE             1930
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_centos6264bit/lv_swap
  LV Name                lv_swap
  VG Name                vg_centos6264bit
  LV UUID                Ukf2if-IlyB-95nM-8Gdq-XXI8-PcKT-fddsqR
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ,
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.97 GiB
  Current LE             504
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1



[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_centos6264bit
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               9.51 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2434
  Alloc PE / Size       2434 / 9.51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               gG9yNW-Jq57-pFkY-oydY-5R4h-oHS0-W7QoWO


[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_centos6264bit/lv_root' [7.54 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_centos6264bit/lv_swap' [1.97 GiB] inherit

[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               vg_centos6264bit
  PV Size               9.51 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2434
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          2434
  PV UUID               8sR1Mg-e4Pa-2FRI-hl1l-N4ns-mKjI-aszG8Y

[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# vgdisplay vg_centos6264bit
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_centos6264bit
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               9.51 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2434
  Alloc PE / Size       2434 / 9.51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               gG9yNW-Jq57-pFkY-oydY-5R4h-oHS0-W7QoWO

[root@IctThtSoluti-06 ~]# cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Feb  4 21:48:23 2014
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_centos6264bit-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=795a0581-67ec-4fa0-ab81-79bb7cc111ab /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_centos6264bit-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

Comment: What does `pvdisplay` show ?

Comment: it is likely that /dev/sda2 is the volume group vg_centos6264bit. what is the result of `vgdisplay vg_centos6264bit` ?

Comment: @Vinz, added pvdisplay output

Comment: @Archemar, added vgdisplay vg_centos6264bit output

Comment: @bpgergo Looks like sda2 is part of `vg_centos6264bit`, which will prevent you from mounting it on its own from what I can find. Also, `vg_centos6264bit` is already mounted on `/` so is there a need to mount it twice? Normally you can mount a volume just using `mount [volume] [location]` plus options. You can also check your entries in `/etc/fstab` if you want to change what gets mounted automatically.

Comment: @Dave, df -h shows vg_centos6264bit has only 7 GB space, although fdisk -l says /dev/sda have 1030 GB. Where is the missing disk space?

Comment: you need to use fdisk to add a third partition `/dev/sda3` (you've allocated 1-1306 out of 16065 sector)

Comment: @Archemar, I couldn't figure out by myself, I need to create an additional partition, and that will allocate the missing space! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mount a lvm drive directly.

`/dev/sda2` is that partition that contain your root and swap partitions.

`lvdisplay` show you the LV path where you logical volumes are.
This is that path you need to use to mount your volumes

Answer (score 2):

1) create new physical partition /dev/sda3 (and set lvm flag on it ).
Do this in `parted`

```
mkpart primary 0% 100%
set 3 lvm on
q
```

2) extend the existing volume group to include the new /dev/sda3 partition

```
VG_NAME=`vgdisplay  | grep "VG Name"  | awk '{print $3}'`
vgextend $VG_NAME /dev/sda3
```

3) create logical volume (replace x with size in GigaBytes)

```
LV_NAME=/dev/vg_centos6264bit/lv_data
lvcreate -L xG -n $LV_NAME $VG_NAME
```

4) create file system on the logical volumes

```
mkfs.ext4 $LV_NAME
```

5) mount logical volumes

```
mkdir /data
mount $LV_NAME /data
```

Comment: thou shall not `grep | awk`  !! use `=$(vgdisplay | awk '/VG Name { print $3 ; }' )`

Comment: Did you mean to post this answer on a different question? This does something useful (add space to a volume group and create a filesystem on it), but not at all what the question asks.

Comment: @Gilles , yes, this post is supposed to be the answer to the original question. It solves the actual problem I faced on some servers and which is described in the code listing of the original post, and which I would put very simply as, the disk was not usable on the node. Your comment is relevant though, because at the time when I asked the original question, I had no idea what is the real problem, and I guessed I need to 'mount a logical volume'.

Comment: @Gilles, and yes, this is also an answer to a different question, which I posted on a different SO sub, somewhat rephrased, when I started to understand the problem more deeply.